# Flutter - ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx

I am developing a mobile application with Flutter. And I have a code like this:

`PaginationController.dart`:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:keycehennemi/functions/SecureStorage.dart';

class PaginationController extends GetxController {
  RxString ProductImage = RxString("");
}
```

`ListView.dart`:

```
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      paginationController.ProductImage.value = snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["Image"];
    });
    Get.to(const ProductDetailsPage());
  },
```

The page I'm trying to show the image:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:keycehennemi/controllers/PaginationController.dart';

class ProductDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductDetailsPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<ProductDetailsPage> createState() => _ProductDetailsPageState();
}

PaginationController paginationController = PaginationController();

String ImageURL = "";

class _ProductDetailsPageState extends State<ProductDetailsPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      ImageURL = paginationController.ProductImage.value;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.network(ImageURL, fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run these codes, I get an error like this:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I haven't been able to figure it out for days, it bothers me.

When I print the `ProductImage` in the `PaginatonController` I see the value is given. So the value is assigned to `ProductImage`. But I can't display the image on the page I'm trying to display and I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be conventional but this is how i use GetX (It can help you):

First I make a GlobalBindings.dart file:

```
class GlobalBindings implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<PaginationController>(() => PaginationController(),
        fenix: true);
}
```

Then I do this in my void main:

```
void main async {
GlobalBindings().dependencies();
runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Then in my PaginationController.dart:

```
class PaginationController extends GetxController {
  String _productImage = "";
  String get productImage => _productImage;
  
  setProductImage(String value){
    _productImage = value;
    update();
  } 
}
```

Then inside productImage:

```
class ProductDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  ProductDetailsPage({Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
    
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Call GetBuilder anywhere in the app
    return GetBuilder<PaginationController>(builder:(controller)=> Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            if(controller.productImage.isNotEmpty)
            Image.network(controller.productImage, fit: BoxFit.cover),
            TextButton(child:Text("Button"),onPressed:(){
             controller.setProductImage("You can set image url here");
              })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

**Note**: You can use the GetBuilder any where.